# worklight - Regarding error in installing worklight server in tomcat

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Hello all,
               I installed Worklight server with tomcat in windows XP. After that i started 
    the tomcat and i am trying to open worklight console like

```
          start --> programs --> Ibm Worklight --> worklight console

        by this i am getting error like requested resource not found. I dont know what 
exact problem was ? please guide me how to open the worklight console when installing
worklight server with tomcat?
```

Comment: What version of Worklight?

Comment: Can you paste in the exact error message you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

The console can't be accessed until you start the IBM Worklight Server first. The console is just a Web GUI for the server so the shortcut might just be directing to the web location which points to a stopped server. Until the server is running, there is no console layer on top of that.

TOMCAT_HOME\bin\startup.bat

Also, here is the link via IBM docs.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_starting_ibm_worklight_server_apache_tom.html